# how to evaluate currency symbols in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am currently having a bit of an issue with respect to evaluating a currency symbol.

I have the following code:

```
function updateTax(totalTax)
    {   
        var tax = $(".Tax").attr("title", "Tax: " + (touch.formatCurrency(totalTax, currencySymbol, currencyDesc, currencyMode)));
    }
```

which currently returns me the following:

```
Tax: &pound;13.20
```

I am trying to get the currency symbol to evaluate, in this case, should be £ instead of &pound. I am not sure if this is due to being raw html and it needs to be converted or not, but if it is, how would i go about doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do it is you can set the html of an element and read the text

```
function getText (str)
  return $("<div>").html(str).text();
}

console.log(getText("Tax: &pound;13.20"));
```